# how to remove data id wise instead of position using database in android

Tags: java, android, database, android-recyclerview

I have use recyclerView and lost of people in list i can click delete button to remove id and update this is status in database.

Data not position wise either i can delete position wise data delete to prob in next activity 
**I m new in android programming**

**Remove code**

```
private class onSelectListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    int mPosition;

    public onSelectListener(int position) {
        mPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
        People people = alertList.get(mPosition);
        db.updateStatus(people.getId(), "0");
        alertList.remove(mPosition);
        notifyItemRemoved(mPosition);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(mPosition, alertList.size());

    }
}
```

**Mydatabase**

```
 public int updateStatus(String peopleId, String status) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(STATUS, status);
    return sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_PEOPLE, values, ID + "=?",
            new String[]{peopleId});
}
```

Comment: Did you mean you are looking for a way to delete an item in RecyclerView ?

Comment: yes..... @FrançoisL.

Comment: okay i will share my delete code

Answer (score 4):

use this,

```
alertList.remove(alertList.indexOf(ID));
```

this will first get the position of ID fist and then remove it from that position.

Comment: What is ID?@Chetan

Comment: which you want to delete, you can use people.getId();

Comment: I have use this code but some error like:-java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=-1

Comment: where will you get ID from which you want to delete?

Comment: I have select 21 id in database to delete.